# What is equivalent of DateTime.ToOADate() in javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript

How can I get the OADate (OLE Automation date) in javascript? I need to pass my date object  (to my web service) in the form of a double value.

in c#:

```
var d = DateTime.Now.ToOADate();
```

what is the equivalent in js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't modify the web service, you'll have to re-implement `ToOADate()`.

MSDN says,

> An OLE Automation date is implemented as a floating-point number whose
>   integral component is the number of days before or after midnight, 30
>   December 1899, and whose fractional component represents the time on
>   that day divided by 24. For example, midnight, 31 December 1899 is
>   represented by 1.0; 6 A.M., 1 January 1900 is represented by 2.25;
>   midnight, 29 December 1899 is represented by -1.0; and 6 A.M., 29
>   December 1899 is represented by -1.25.

Thus, you should be able to write something like

```
var oaDate = (date - new Date(1899, 11, 31)) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

(untested)

Comment: brilliant, with the change xanatos mentioned, it works perfectly.

Comment: @valipour I think it's off by some hours, depending on DST and similar things. Here in Italy it's off by 1 hour.

Comment: Found. `var oaDate = (date - new Date(Date.UTC(1899, 11, 30))) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)`

Comment: And of course this does not work at all for dates before the epoch!  I used to give this problem as a warmup interview question; this implementation wouldn't get an offer. :-)

Comment: @Eric: That's why I said "something like"; I didn't have time to write a better implementation.  I read your blog post about this a while ago; I'm aware of those issues.

Comment: wow eric. so someone can spout this type of thing off the top of their head in an interview and because you ran into that problem and figured out how to correct it, but they didnt foresee that during your interview you would can them... your an ass

Comment: @VolureDarkAngel: I would assume that the issues would be a little more obvious from the way he presents it in the interview, and that he would give a little back-and-forth before rejecting.  Also, no-one said that an interview at Microsoft would be easy; they only want star developers.

Comment: @SLaks I guess that is a good point. And I would hope a little back and forth is given. I just think that response seemed pretentious at best. I guess tho, when you make stuff up you can be mad when people don't get it. but hey. Even Microsoft didn't get it right the first time. Should we can the whole excel team cause they had a bug ? The comment gave good information regarding the bug. but it also showed his character. Unimpressive.

Comment: This should be: 
var oaDate = (date - new Date(Date.UTC(1899, 12, 29))) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)

Answer (score 9):

To convert a JScript date to an OLE Automation date, call getVarDate:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d4x3w61(VS.85).aspx

(If you go *the other way* -- that is, you have a JScript object and you assign a property containing a variant of VT_DATE type -- the JScript engine should automatically convert that to the equivalent JScript date.)

If your browser provider did not do you the courtesy of writing a getVarDate method, well, 
it is not difficult to write the code yourself, but in order to get it right for all cases you have to handle some tricky special cases involving dates before the epoch.

The best way I know of to get the code right is to first convert it to the raw number of whole and fractional days since the epoch, which I note is midnight of December *30*, not *31*, 1899. Once you have that, you can special-case the before-epoch values.

Be very careful about rounding! I recommend that you round values off to the nearest second *before* you do the conversion to the OA format. Because the OA format is one where -1.9999999 is just before midnight December 30th 1899, but -2.0 is midnight December 28th, if you round the former to the latter, you just rounded a fraction of a second off into a two-day error.

For the details on the quirks of the OA format, see my article from 2003 on the subject:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/16/53013.aspx

And for an entertaining look at the deeper history of this odd date format, see Joel's article about his Microsoft days:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/06/16.html

Answer (score 4):

markitondemand@Github solved it in the following way and it accounts for DST

https://github.com/markitondemand/moment-msdate/blob/master/moment-msdate.js

```
toOADate: function (date) {
    var timezoneOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset() / (60 * 24);
    var msDateObj = (date.getTime() / 86400000) + (25569 - timezoneOffset);
    return msDateObj;
 },
fromOADate: function (oadate) {
   var date = new Date(((oadate - 25569) * 86400000));
   var tz = date.getTimezoneOffset();
   return new Date(((oadate - 25569 + (tz / (60 * 24))) * 86400000));
},
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that works for DST dates as well:

```
var toOADate = (function () {
    /** @const */ var utc18991230 = Date.UTC(1899, 11, 31);
    /** @const */ var msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    return function (date) {
        if (date instanceof Date) {
            date = Date.UTC(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate());
        }
        return (date - utc18991230) / msPerDay;
    };

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Those look good for JS above, but if you want to do convert it into a Unix timestamp in PHP, use the following:

```
// $ms_date_floating_point is the MS date
// 42372.3432210648 converts to Sun Jan 3rd, 2016
$ms_date_seconds = $ms_date_floating_point * 60 * 60 * 24;
$unix_timestamp_seconds = strtotime("Nov 11, 1899 00:00:00") + $ms_date_seconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

with time zone offset repair:

```
function toOADate(date) {
    var msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    var baseDate = new Date("1899-12-30T00:00:00.000+0000");
    return (date.getTime() - baseDate.getTime() - 60*1000*getTimezoneOffset()) / msPerDay;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should change your webservice to take a UNIX timestamp.

You can then call `new Date().getTime()` in Javascript, or `(someDate - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds` in C#.

Comment: what if it's another person's webservice and I can not change it?