# OADate to Milliseconds timestamp in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, timestamp

I try to do the exact opposite of :

[What is equivalent of DateTime.ToOADate() in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348805/what-is-equivalent-of-datetime-tooadate-in-javascript)

Create a millisecond date (number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970)  from a OADate (number of  days since 30 dec 1899 as a double value)

my guess is I can do like this :

```
this.unixTimeStampFromOADate = function( OADateFloat)
{
        var oaDateFor1970 = ?? ; //what's the value for 1/1/1970 in OADate format ?
        var delta = Math.floor(OADateFloat - oaDateFor1970);

        return delta*(1000*60*60*24); 
}
```

so if I'm right, I need the value for 1/1/1970 in OADate format.
if I'm wrong, please can you suggest another conversion method ?

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348805/what-is-equivalent-of-datetime-tooadate-in-javascript

Comment: Just compute it with the formula given in that question. If you pass in `new Date(0)`, you get out the oaDate `25569`

Comment: it should be the exact number of day from 1899 dec 30 to 1970 1/1. :/

Comment: @Mark its the exact opposite opperation I'm looking for

Comment: oh yeah bergi thx  so simple why didn't I think about it XD ^^  so are you agree with my function ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript dates use a time value that is milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. The time value for the date 1899-12-30 is -2209197600000.

To get the days since then, get the milliseconds for midnight at the start of today, subtract it from the OA epoch, divide by the ms in one day and get the absolute value. Note that the time values are all UTC so daylight saving, leap years, etc. are accounted for.

```
var epoch = new Date(1899, 11, 30); // 1899-12-30T00:00:00
var now = new Date();               // 2013-03-22T<current time>
now.setHours(0,0,0,0)               // 2013-03-22T00:00:00

var oaDate  = Math.abs((epoch - now) / 8.64e7); // 41355 for 2013-03-22
```

You can test it against some dates [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/fromoadate) (note that those dates are in the confusing US m/d/yy format).

#### Edit

Sorry, got the sense backwards. Here are some functions to go both ways.

Also took some time to work out that where it says "OLE Automation date is implemented as a floating-point number whose integral component is the number of days before or after midnight, 30 December 1899" actually means on or after 1899-12-30 00:00:00 and that the "fractional component represents the time on that day divided by 24". In other words, while 1899-12-29 00:00:00 is -1, the value for `899-12-29 06:00:00 is -1.25, not -0.75.

Anyhow, these functions seem to work now, but please test thoroughly:

```
var toOADate = (function () {
  var epoch = new Date(1899,11,30);
  var msPerDay = 8.64e7;

  return function(d) {
    var v = -1 * (epoch - d)/msPerDay;

    // Deal with dates prior to 1899-12-30 00:00:00
    var dec = v - Math.floor(v);

    if (v < 0 && dec) {
      v = Math.floor(v) - dec;
    }

    return v;
  }
}());


var fromOADate = (function() {
  var epoch = new Date(1899,11,30);
  var msPerDay = 8.64e7;

  return function(n) {
    // Deal with -ve values
    var dec = n - Math.floor(n);

    if (n < 0 && dec) {
      n = Math.floor(n) - dec;
    }

    return new Date(n*msPerDay + +epoch);
  }
}());

var now = new Date();
var oaNow = toOADate(now);
var now2 = fromOADate(oaNow);

alert('Today: ' + now + '\nOADate: ' + oaNow + '\noaNow to Date: ' + now2);
```

The specification for [OADate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate.aspx) is confusing, particularly the way negative numbers are handled.

#### Edit Feb 2019

Updated version of functions, use local date values.

```js
/* Convert a Microsoft OADate to ECMAScript Date
** Treat all values as local.
** @param {string|number} oaDate - OADate value
** @returns {Date}
*/
function dateFromOADate (oaDate) {
  // Treat integer part is whole days
  var days = parseInt(oaDate);
  // Treat decimal part as part of 24hr day, always +ve
  var ms = Math.abs((oaDate - days) * 8.64e7);
  // Add days and add ms
  return new Date(1899, 11, 30 + days, 0, 0, 0, ms);
}


/* Convert an ECMAScript Date to a Microsoft OADate
** Treat all dates as local.
** @param {Date} date - Date to convert
** @returns {Date}
*/
function dateToOADate (date) {
  var temp = new Date(date);
  // Set temp to start of day and get whole days between dates,
  var days = Math.round((temp.setHours(0,0,0,0) - new Date(1899, 11, 30)) / 8.64e7);
  // Get decimal part of day, OADate always assumes 24 hours in day
  var partDay = (Math.abs((date - temp) % 8.64e7) / 8.64e7).toFixed(10);
  return days + partDay.substr(1);
}

var now = new Date();
var x = dateToOADate(now);
console.log('Now: ' + now.toString());
console.log('As an OADate: ' + x);
console.log('Back to date: ' + dateFromOADate(x).toString());

window.onload = function(){ 
  var el = document.getElementById('in')
  el.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var oaDate = dateToOADate(new Date(new Date(el.value)));
    document.getElementById('out').value = oaDate;
    document.getElementById('out2').value = dateFromOADate(oaDate);
  });
}
```

```css
input {width: 25em}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Input date:<br>(DD MMM YYYY HH:mm)
    <td><input id="in" value="29 Dec 1899 06:00">
  <tr>
    <td>OA Date:
    <td><input id="out" readonly>
  <tr>
    <td>Back to standard date:
    <td><input id="out2" readonly>
</table>
```

Comment: +1, although you'll need to use `Date.UTC` for the `epoch` constructions - otherwise only those living in GMT will get happy

Comment: I considered that, but all dates are created as local so will have the local offset factored in, so it should cancel out. Strictly though, they should probably all use UTC values but I could not see any reference to UTC in the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate.aspx).

Comment: The primary reason to use UTC is to allow for time zones by using a common base, however OA Dates don't have any allowance for time zone so it doesn't seem sensible to attempt to account for it. Converting 2013-03T23:59:59 to an OA Date will return  41355.99998842592, reversing it gives back the same date and time (all in the current time zone). Converting to UTC and back internally will give exactly the same result. If the OA Date value is used across time zones, it's effectively the same as passing date and time strings across time zones with no time zone offset information.

Comment: "*it's effectively the same as passing date and time strings across time zones with no time zone offset information*" - OK, only I don't know whether that's desirable :-) I'm not familiar with .NET, though it looks as you can set the [DateTimeKind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921.aspx) to let them represent either local or utc dates. At least you should document your functions, stating that they encode/decode the local time values