# Javascript convert short date number to javascript date

Tags: javascript, date, xlsx, js-xlsx

I have a `.xlsx` file which has a table which contains dates. When I read the table in to javascript (with xlsx nodejs package) the dates are formatted as numbers. I would like to convert these numbers to dates. For example the number 43527 should be the date 13/03/2019. I have tried `new Date(43527*60*60*24*1000)` but this gives the wrong answer of `2089-03-04T00:00:00.000Z`.

Comment: Is there any logic for it like 43527 should be equal to given date?

Comment: A javascript date is based on Jan 1 1970 and an Excel date is based on Jan 1 1900.  More info about Excel date storage [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252)

Comment: Actually, 43527 corresponds to '03-Mar-2019'

Comment: @James—the JS epoch is 0, but the Excel ([OADate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate.aspx)) epoch day is 1, which, confusingly, makes 1 Jan 1900 day 2. In ECMAScript terms, the equivalent OADate epoch is 30 Dec 1899. Try it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15550284/257182).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel stores dates internally using OLE Automation Date (OADate).

The base OLE Automation Date is midnight, 30 December 1899. OLE Automation date is implemented as a floating-point number whose **integral component is the number of days before or after midnight, 30 December 1899,** and whose fractional component represents the time on that day divided by 24. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tooadate?view=netcore-3.1#remarks]

You need to subtract 25,569, which is the number of days between 30 December 1899 and 1 January 1970, before converting to milliseconds.

To convert the date:

```js
var excelDate = 43527;
var parsedDate = new Date((excelDate - 25569) * 86400 * 1000)).toISOString();
```

As mentioned here [Converting Excel Date Serial Number to Date using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229494/converting-excel-date-serial-number-to-date-using-javascript/22352911#22352911)

Comment: Indeed not needed, thanks.

Comment: `*86400*1000` may be shortened to `*864e5`

Comment: If you've found a duplicate answer, you should mark this question as a duplicate, not copy or rewrite an answer from the duplicate. If you have a better answer, post it at the duplicate. Excel uses OADate, the epoch is 30 Dec 1899, not 1 Jan 1900.