# Unable to DATE VALUE using XLSX Library Javascript

Tags: javascript, npm, xlsx

I need to separate all the headers of Excel sheet. code that i implemented is working but only text format is working. kindly help.

```
const xlsx = require('xlsx');

const workbook = xlsx.readFile('./SMALL.xlsx');
const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];

const workbookHeaders = xlsx.readFile('./SMALL.xlsx', { sheetRows: 1 });
const columnsArray = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(workbookHeaders.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]], { header: 1 })[0];


console.log(columnsArray);
```

Response

My console should print ['Task', '1/2022', '2/2022' ]. instead its printing
[ 'Task', 44562, 44593 ]

[image: Image of console/node output and spreadsheet cells]

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by _"but only text format is working"_. Please give as much detail about what is not working for you, what are you expecting the result to be and how does it differ from what you actually get?

Comment: Sorry. i have modified a bit. please read now

Comment: Right... Date values are stored as a serial number of days since 31st December 1899 - this is the value you are getting. The `01/2022` is the result of formatting this serial number and not the actual stored value.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61896377/javascript-convert-short-date-number-to-javascript-date for more info on converting 44562 to a JavaScript Date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can specify a date format string in the options parameter to the `sheet_to_json(worksheet, opts)` method.

The option property name appears to be: dateNF

https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#parsing-options