# Date format changing when converting xlsx to json

Tags: javascript, json, angular, primeng

I am trying to read data form xlsx file and converting it into json, but the date column value is changing
Here is the screenshot:[Screenshot of my excel file from which i am reading data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imdtZ.png)

Here is the code for reading data from excel file and converting into JSON:

```
onBasicUpload(event){
let workBook = null;
let jsonData = null;
const reader = new FileReader();
const file = event.files[0];
console.log(file,"file is here");

reader.onload = (event) => {
  const data = reader.result;
  workBook = xlsx.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
  jsonData = workBook.SheetNames.reduce((initial, name) => {
    const sheet = workBook.Sheets[name];
    initial[name] = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet);
    console.log(jsonData,"jsonDAta");
    
    return initial;
  }, {});
  const dataString = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
  console.log(dataString,"stringify data");
  this.jsonArr = JSON.parse(dataString)
  console.log(this.jsonArr,"parsed json");
  console.log(Object.keys(this.jsonArr['data'][0]))
  
}
reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}
```

It is returning me this:
DOCDT is the value of the date being returned.
**{"data":[{"DOCNO":"001","NETAMOUNT":30000,"IREF1":"50","IREF2":"100","DOCDT":43989},{"DOCNO":2,"NETAMOUNT":40000,"IREF1":40,"IREF2":90,"DOCDT":43989}]}**

Comment: That's because Excel stores dates and times as a number of days since an epoch, midnight on 30 December 1899 (IIRC).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549823/oadate-to-milliseconds-timestamp-in-javascript for a way to convert this number to a JavaScript Date.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OADate to Milliseconds timestamp in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549823/oadate-to-milliseconds-timestamp-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this,

```
onBasicUpload(event){
let workBook = null;
let jsonData = null;
const reader = new FileReader();
const file = event.files[0];
console.log(file,"file is here");

reader.onload = (event) => {
  const data = reader.result;
  workBook = xlsx.read(data, { type: 'binary' , cellDates: true });
  jsonData = workBook.SheetNames.reduce((initial, name) => {
    const sheet = workBook.Sheets[name];
    initial[name] = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet);
    console.log(jsonData,"jsonDAta");
    
    return initial;
  }, {});
  const dataString = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
  console.log(dataString,"stringify data");
  this.jsonArr = JSON.parse(dataString)
  console.log(this.jsonArr,"parsed json");
  console.log(Object.keys(this.jsonArr['data'][0]))
  
}
reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}
```

Comment: Tried it! but no success :( Thanks for your response :)

Comment: Yes, i got the date but in long format, is there any way to format this as given in my excel sheet. Thank you for help! much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Dates are storred as a number within XLSX Files (See [here](https://excel.tips.net/T002176_How_Excel_Stores_Dates_and_Times.html) or [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_dates_and_time.html)). What you got is what is storred, so you got the number back.

According to the first reference, dates are storred as of January 1 1900. All you need to do now is have a function, that converts this number back to a date. Pure math.

Luckily, a quick SO search revealed, that this has been done before:
[Converting Excel Date Serial Number to Date using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229494/converting-excel-date-serial-number-to-date-using-javascript)

Comment: Actually i used the code from this website https://stackblitz.com/edit/xlsx-to-json?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts It is returning the correct date value if i try running the example given in this website.