# Pass date to ADODB.Command parameter from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, asp-classic, ado

Using old-timey classic ADO, *not* ADO.NET, how do you pass a date value to a stored procedure from JavaScript? The JS is running in a classic ASP page on IIS7. SQL Server is 2012 (1).

SOLVED: See answer below. Long story short, the results were finding their way back to me via a JSON stringifier that ignored properties with variant date values.

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
create procedure test(@n int, @d datetime)
as
begin
    select @n n, @d d;
end;
```

And I have some JavaScript code in a classic ASP page:

```
var conn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var cmd = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Command");

conn.Open(connectionString);

cmd.ActiveConnection = conn;

cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc;
cmd.CommandText = 'dbo.test';

cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter('@n', adInteger, adParamInput, 4, 123));

var param = cmd.CreateParameter('@d', adDate, adParamInput);

param.Value = (new Date('01/01/2000')).getVarDate();

cmd.Parameters.Append(param);

var rs = cmd.Execute();
```

What I get back from the SP always has the expected value for `@n` (123, above), and always has `null` for `@d`. `connectionString` must be OK because it does call the SP, and it's definitely the SP I think I'm calling; if I make changes to it, they are reflected in what comes back.

I get the `getVarDate()` from [Eric Lippert's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348805/what-is-equivalent-of-datetime-tooadate-in-javascript/7349381#7349381). I have also tried `adDBDate` with various data types.

I wrote the above test SP for testing purposes; you may have noticed that it doesn't do very much useful work. In production, I have to pass a date to an existing SP. The details of that SP wouldn't lend much clarity to this question. I *can*, if I absolutely must, write a wrapper SP that receives a date as a string and converts it. But I want to understand what is wrong here, and we have more than enough semi-redundant SPs cluttering up the database already. And that's just a horrible way to do things.

(1) @@version = 'Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3381.0 (X64)   Aug 23 2013 20:08:13   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0  (Build 6002: Service Pack 2) (Hypervisor)'

Comment: Is `ad.ParamInput` a typo?

Comment: @Kul-Tigin Yes it is, thanks. Corrected.

Comment: It works for me. If the problem still exists after the correcting typo, you may want to share your connection string. Some drivers / providers may lead to problems like this.

Comment: Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI

Comment: I used the same provider with no problem but on SQL Server 2008 R2. I can say only that it seems like a problem depending on the SQL Server version.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin Oh, wow. Got it: `getVarDate()` works fine. `adDBDate` works fine if you just pass it '1900-01-01' as a string. The problem was my code **dealing with what came back**. If the SP selects a datetime, I get null from `rs.Fields.Item("d").Value`. If I change the SP to `select convert(varchar,@d)`, I get the stringified date back.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin Thanks very much for looking at this -- I'm sorry I wasted your time!

Comment: Oh don't be. Frankly, all of my attempts specifying `adDBDate`, `adDate` and `adDBTimestamp` was successful. BTW I passed an OLE Date variable (thorugh getVarDate) not string or something else. I think your development environment a little bit weird :) Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, what's coming back from the SP turns out to be `adDBTimeStamp`.

Comment: If you solved this then please put the solution as a new answer.

Comment: A good resource for cases like this is **[Carl Prothman - Data Type Mapping](http://www.carlprothman.net/Technology/DataTypeMapping/tabid/97/Default.aspx)** it shows that `adDBTimeStamp` is equivalent to `datetime` and `smalldatetime` in SQL Server.

Comment: @EdPlunkett As Shadow Wizard suggests would recommend you post your solution as a new answer then select it as the accepted answer. See [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out; I was so wrong, I didn't even mention the part that was actually causing the problem.

`rs.Fields.Item("d").Value` returns a variant of type `adDBTimeStamp`.

This is in an ASP that's acting as a web service and returning JSON, and [the JSON stringifier I'm using](http://dragonfly.opera.com/app/jsDoc/jsDoc/overview-summary-json.js.html) just ignores properties with `adDBTimeStamp` values. Everything was coming back fine from the DB, then getting dropped later.

It actually turns out that ADODB.Command's `CreateParameter` method is very obliging about handling dates.

So:

```
var rs = RecordSetToObjArray(cmd.Execute();

//  ...

//  Convert variant dates into something the JSON stringifier groks. 
function GetADOFieldValue(field) {
    switch (field.Type) {
        case adDBTimeStamp:
        case adDate:
        case adDBDate:
        case adDBTime:
        case adFileTime:
            if ('undefined' === '' + field.Value)
                return null;
            return new Date('' + field.Value);

        default:
            return field.Value;
    }
}

//  Given recordset from ADODBCommand.Execute(), return as array of JSON 
//  objects. 
//  Also convert variant dates into something the JSON stringifier groks. 
//  If an SP returns multiple recordsets, that's on you. 
function RecordSetToObjArray(rs) {
    var rtn = [];
    var fieldNames = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < rs.Fields.Count; ++i) {
        fieldNames.push(rs.Fields.Item(i).Name);
    }

    rtn.FieldNames = fieldNames;

    while (!rs.EOF) {
        var rec = {};

        for (var i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; ++i) {
            rec[fieldNames[i]] = GetADOFieldValue(rs.Fields.Item(fieldNames[i]));
        }
        rtn.push(rec);
        rs.MoveNext();
    }

    return rtn;
}

function RecordSetToScalar(rs) {
    if (rs.RecordCount == 0 || rs.Fields.Count == 0)
        return null;
    return GetADOFieldValue(rs.Fields.Item(0));
}
```