# php ocibindbyname equivalent in javascript

Tags: javascript, oracle

I'm using a hta page written in javascript to monitor some oracle tables.

I'd like to use the bind variables to optimize the oracle query caching as i did in php environmet with this code:

```
$sql = "select m1_master from CEDWORK.hd_anag where account = :utente";
$s = OCIParse($c, $sql);
ocibindbyname($s, ":utente", $utente);
if ( OCIExecute($s, OCI_DEFAULT) == false ){
   gsterr($sql, "record not found");
}
 while (ocifetch($s)) {
       $codmec = OCIResult($s, "M1_MASTER");
}
```

In hta javascript I used this code:

```
function test1(idUtente){
  var adOpenDynamic = 2
  var adLockOptimistic = 3
  var conn_str = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Password=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxx;Data Source=sgo01";
 var conn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection")
 conn.open(conn_str)
 var rsPass = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
 var arrPass = new Array();
 var rs2arr = new Array();
 var  SQLpass = "SELECT  cod_operatore, a.cognome, a.nome, a.account, m1_master ";   
 SQLpass += "from cedwork.hd_operatori a, cedwork.hd_anag b " ;
 SQLpass += "where a.account = b.account " ;
 SQLpass += "and  a.account = '" + idUtente + "'" ;

 rsPass.open(SQLpass, conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic);
 alert(rsPass.fields("m1_master").value);
 rsPass.close();
```

}

I'd like to replace the "idUtente"  variable with a bind variable  but i did not found the javascript sintiax....

Thanks for any help,
Marco

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/20749733/1509264 - use `"ADODB.Command"` to create a prepared statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat - I do not use ADODB but some judicious searching on "ADODB" "prepared statements" and "bind variables" got answers from:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676102(v=vs.85).aspx
- [Pass date to ADODB.Command parameter from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20749733/pass-date-to-adodb-command-parameter-from-javascript)

Which suggests this answer:

```
var conn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var cmd  = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Command");
var rs   = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
conn.open( "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Password=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True;"
           + "User ID=xxxx;Data Source=sgo01" );
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT  cod_operatore, a.cognome, a.nome, a.account, m1_master "
                  + "FROM cedwork.hd_operatori a "
                  + "INNER JOIN cedwork.hd_anag b "
                  + "ON ( a.account = b.account ) "
                  + "WHERE a.account = ?";
cmd.Parameters.Append(
  cmd.CreateParameter( "id", adChar, adParamInput, 20, idUtente )
);
rs = cmd.Execute();
```