# SmallDateTime Overflow only on remote test server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have an application where the user uploads an data excel file to a database table, all columns are in the same order of the excel and database table.

I use OpenXML SDK to do the parsing and a switch/case to adjust certain fields types to avoid errors.

```
 public static object ConvertToExpectedType(string value, SqlDbType sqlType)
        {
            switch (sqlType)
            {
                ...

            case SqlDbType.SmallDateTime:
            case SqlDbType.DateTime:
            case SqlDbType.Date:
            case SqlDbType.DateTime2:
                return ParseExcelDate(value, SqlDbType.DateTime);
            case SqlDbType.Time:
                return ParseExcelDate(value, SqlDbType.Time).TimeOfDay;

            ...

        }
    }

    public static DateTime ParseExcelDate(this string date, SqlDbType type)
    {
        if (date.Equals("null", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return new DateTime(1900, 01, 01);

        DateTime dt;

        if (DateTime.TryParse(date, culture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault,out dt))
        {
            return dt;
        }

        double oaDate;
        if (double.TryParse(date,  NumberStyles.Float, culture,out oaDate))
        {
            return DateTime.FromOADate(oaDate);
        }

        return new DateTime(1900, 01, 01);
    }
```

In my dev enviroment (Release and Debug modes) the application works just fine, however when I publish it to my server I get this exception from one of the files:

> SqlDbType.SmallDateTime overflow.  Value '12/31/1899 00:00:00' is out
>   of range.  Must be between 1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM and 6/6/2079 11:59:59
>   PM.;

The application works fine even when I set my connection string to the remote database in VS.

Has anyone run into this problem before? 
Any ideas how to fix it or do different tests to identify where the problem is?

Full Exception

```
System.OverflowException: SqlDbType.SmallDateTime overflow.  Value '12/31/1899 00:00:00' is out of range.  Must be between 1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM and 6/6/2079 11:59:59 PM.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.WriteUnterminatedValue(Object value, MetaType type, Byte scale, Int32 actualLength, Int32 encodingByteSize, Int32 offset, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Int32 paramSize, Boolean isDataFeed)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.WriteBulkCopyValue(Object value, SqlMetaDataPriv metadata, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isSqlType, Boolean isDataFeed, Boolean isNull)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.ReadWriteColumnValueAsync(Int32 col)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyColumnsAsync(Int32 col, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyRowsAsync(Int32 rowsSoFar, Int32 totalRows, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsyncContinued(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsync(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalRestContinuedAsync(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalRestAsync(CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalAsync(CancellationToken ctoken)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteRowSourceToServerAsync(Int32 columnCount, CancellationToken ctoken)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable table, DataRowState rowState)
   at PVINOVA_FIleUploader_v1._0.Models.MSqlServer.MSqlServerDbContext.InsertRecordsSqlBulkCopy(DataTable dt, SqlTransaction transaction, List`1 TableSchema, FileType fileType, String errLogPath)
```

Thanks in advance!

**Update!!! Found the field that is having problem**

I extracted to CSV file the batch that is having problem to find out the wrong date.

The original file comes with value 01/01/1900 but after the treatments on the field (Method ParseExcelDate mentioned above) somehow the field becomes 12/31/1899.

*Also, the other date values are matching with original file*

I thought about two possible solutions but I still dont understand why this happened so I'm not comfortable on fixing yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check your variables values, when this error occurs?

Comment: Can you capture which line throwing the error after publishing (suggested using try...catch block and display entire error message in custom error page)? Also which kind of Excel data triggering exception? Include error stack trace if necessary.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.
The file that I`m working on has 42k rows, I did manage to extract to CSV the batch of 1k rows that was having the problem, however all the smalldatetime columns (Only 2) are ok, and only one value is initiated as 1900-01-01, some are set as "Null" which  I convert to default value of 1900...

*But something caught my eye, the csv file is out of order in some fields, I mean, the columns shifted which may be the source of the problem, or it might just be the code to convert datatable to csv that is wrong.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I finally manage to find te field that is having problem. Check the post update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When parsing values from excel using OpenXML SDK, dates come as float numbers (ie. 45231,4221). Since the field value was 1900-01-01 = 1.0 .Net converted to it's own default value which is 1899-12-30 = 1.0.

To fix it I made one more condition to the first If Statement in the method "ParseExcelDate"

```
public static DateTime ParseExcelDate(this string date, SqlDbType type)
        {
            if (date.Equals("null", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || date.Equals("1.0"))
                return new DateTime(1900, 01, 01);
...
```

This post helped me get to this solution: [What is equivalent of DateTime.ToOADate() in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348805/what-is-equivalent-of-datetime-tooadate-in-javascript)

*But I still don't know how it worked on my local machine but not on the server*